# SaxParser Eception while reading <mappings> from dozer-mapping.xml

Tags: java, dozer

I am trying to implemet DOZER in my project. I am getting SAX Exception. PFB, the details

> org.dozer.MappingException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Parsing Error
>   Line:    4
>   URI:     null
>   Message: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mappings'.
>       at org.dozer.util.MappingUtils.throwMappingException(MappingUtils.java:82)
>       at org.dozer.loader.xml.MappingStreamReader.read(MappingStreamReader.java:55)
>       at org.dozer.loader.xml.MappingFileReader.read(MappingFileReader.java:58)
>       at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadFromFiles(DozerBeanMapper.java:227)
>       at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadCustomMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:209)
>       at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.initMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:315)
>       at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.getMappingProcessor(DozerBeanMapper.java:192)
>       at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:120)

My dozer-mapping.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns:ns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net 
           http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
  <mapping>
<class-a>org.esb.ClassA</class-a>
<class-b>org.esb.ClassB</class-b>
<field>
    <a>status</a>
    <b>statusCode</b>
</field>
 </mapping>
</mappings>
```

My java code:

```
destinationObj= dozerBeanMapper.map(sourceObj, DestinationClass.class);
```

Jars Used:

Dozer 5.4.0.jar, commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar, log4j-1.2.15.jar, slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar

Comment: I am not familiar with dozer, but I see something wrong in your XML: You are declaring the namespace "http://dozer.sourceforge.net" (according to the XSD) binding it to the prefix "ns". But you never use it! I think, you wanted to do "<ns:mappings>...</ns:mappings>". Like you did, your <mappings> element has no namespace, so the error message is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this `xmlns:ns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"` the schema would work for your xml only in the `ns` namespace.

Instead you should write `xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"` as in [this dozer-example](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html#).